# Does initializing std::vector with `{{}}` cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I think I didn't understand the initialization of `std::vector`.

The code below seems to compile and run fine with gcc, clang, and MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{{}};

    v[10] = 11; // if initialize with v{}, segmentation fault.

    std::cout << "v[10]:" << v[10] << std::endl; // prints v[10]:11
    
    for (auto e : v) // prints only v[x]:0
        std::cout << "v[x]:" << e << std::endl;    
}

// result:
// v[10]:11
// v[x]:0
```

Is accessing the element with `v[10]` causing an undefined behavior?

Why does the above code with `v{{}}` run fine, but not with `v{}`?

Edit) Originally I didn't use the correct terminology, my fault. When I said 'not compiled', I was trying to say 'not run(after compile)'.

Comment: Your title seems off. It's not the initialization of the vector that causes undefined behavior, but the out-of-bounds access. The initialization merely changes how that undefined behavior manifests.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/GEY95aYhz).

Comment: What happened to me... Sorry I was trying to say 'not run', not 'not compile'. @bolov Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> v{};
```

This initializes `v` as a vector of size `0`. Attempting to access any element in it results in Undefined Behavior. `v[10]` is out of bounds and UB.

```
std::vector<int> v{{}};
```

This initializes `v` as a vector with a single element. That single element is initialized with `{}` i.e. `int{}` i.e. `0`. Attempting to access any element except `v[0]` results in UB. `v[10]` causes UB.